# approach to include different Attribution when map is going to be exported to png

Tags: javascript, openlayers-3

I enhanced the export-png example and managed to include the scale and the overviewmap into the canvas context when the user is clicking the export-to-image button.

Now I try to include the [Attributions](http://openlayers.org/en/master/apidoc/ol.Attribution.html) to the exported canvas-context as well.

Beacuse the of the policies of some sources a link is demanded and I have to use HTML in that attributions. When I add these to the canvas the html code is not useful at all, of course :-)

Unfortunatly the class ol.Attribution don't offer that much flexibelty for my requirement, yet.

I thought I could create an object, like:

```
var ATTRIBUTION = {
    source1: {
        online: 'Source: XYZ, © <a href="http://sourcewebsite.xyz>Provider</a>',
        print: 'Source: XYZ © Provider'
    }
}
```

And calling it in the source with

```
attributions: [
    new ol.Attribution({
        html: ATTRIBUTION.source1
    })]
```

And then to decide which one will be shown. ATTRIBUTION.source1.online in the map application and ATTRIBUTION.source1.print when the Export-image is created.

Anyone have an idea how I could solve this?

I tried

```
attributions: [
new ol.Attribution({
    html: ATTRIBUTION.source1.online,
    custom: ATTRIBUTION.source1.print
})]
```

But I didn't managed to get this working beacuse of the lack of possibilites in the class `ol.Attribution` in this OL3-Version (3.7.0.)

When I add more than one attribution all of them will be shown. Not that what I want. I could regex all the HTML out of the attribution before I add it to the canvas-context. But thats just nasty. Or I could do some CSS with `display:none` and stuff. But again - not very elegant.

Thank you

Comment: OK i just forgot that i can add custom objects to the source itself. So I did this and use a second object PRINT_Attribution with properties.
`new ol.source.TileWMS({ 
 url = ...;
attributions: ...;
printattributions: PRINT_Attribution.source1;
})`

Comment: ... ok `layer.getSource().get('print_attr')` returns undefined. That approach doesn't work unless I add the custom object `print_attr` to the layer...

Comment: If you set the attribute with `source.set('test', 1234);` and get the value again with `source.get('test')` it should work.

Comment: Thank you. This way it works. But why only this way?